# Android reference resource of unknown package upfront

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lets say that in `Components module` I am creating a `Fragment` with layout file `fragment.xml` where one of the `TextView` is rendering `android:text="@string/resource1"`

Now I want to reuse the `Fragment` in `App module` but this time, the app would like to provide value that needs to be rendered. So far I have found only the option to create an `open fun provideResource():Int` on `Fragment` and inside set the `TextView.setText()`. The consumer of the `Fragment` will need to inherit the `Fragment` and provide the id in this method. But I don't like it. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: You can re-use the fragment without any issue & provide the value via arguments with the transaction.  What's the issue here

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa agree, I just wanted to know if there is some alternative like when you use ?attr it will look on value of theme, something similar with @string/res given that i dont know the package id upfront